# Injection scripts in Safari extensions don't fire in Youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube, safari, safari-extension

While creating a Safari extension, I tried adding an End Script on Youtube pages. The script runs when the first Youtube page loads. The problem is that if I click any of the Youtube links in the page, nothing happens. However, if I open the link in a new tab, it works like a charm. Any idea why this happens?

The code is just a simple alert:

```
if (window.top === window) {
    alert("Hello World");
}
```

and the pattern I used for the Allowed Domains is:

*.youtube.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube is a single page application. It loads required parts via XHR without reloading the page.

You can use dom mutation events to detect changes.

Comment: Related tags: [tag:mutation-events] and [tag:mutation-observers]